# AntClassLoader cannot be cast to URLClassLoader

Tags: java, jsp, ant

I have an Ant task to compile jsp files with Jasper. The first step is generate the java files:

```
<java classname="org.apache.jasper.JspC" fork="no" failonerror="true">
    <classpath refid="my.class.path" />
    <arg value="-uriroot" />
    <arg value="${apps}" />
    <arg value="-d" />
    <arg value="${jsp}" />
    <arg value="-p" />
    <arg value="my.package.jsp" />
    <arg value="-webinc" />
    <arg value="${apps}/META-INF/gen-mappings.xml" />
    <arg value="-webapp" />
    <arg value="${apps}" />
</java>
```

When I launch this task I get:

```
BUILD FAILED
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader cannot be cast
 to java.net.URLClassLoader
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext.<init>(JspRuntimeContext
.java:113)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspC.initServletContext(JspC.java:1257)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1118)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspC.main(JspC.java:243)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        ...
```

How can I manage this problem?
Thanks!

Claudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.
For a wrong dependency chain between the Ant tasks, the web application folder was empty, without any JSP.
Corrected the chain and launched the jasper task with some JSP, all is ok.
Thanks for help.
Claudio

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're supposed to invoke `JspC` directly like that. Tomcat provides an Ant task specifically for this purposes, it may do the necessary classloader gymnastics for you

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jasper-howto.html#Web%20Application%20Compilation

```
<jasper 
         validateXml="false" 
         uriroot="${webapp.path}" 
         webXmlFragment="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/generated_web.xml" 
         outputDir="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/src" />
```

Comment: Same problem even with this modification.

Comment: I would generally agree with using a jasper task, but there are several options available as command line switches, but lacking setters in JspC class.  For OP's problem I would also recommend using `jasper` task.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
fork="true"
```

to launch a separate JVM, rather than inheriting the Ant JVM.

Comment: Same problem even with this modification.

Comment: it worked though in my case when I was getting the same exception (Java SE setting, not web)